# Jetty configuration: problems with MySQL JNDI

Tags: mysql, xml, gradle, jetty, embedded-jetty

The Jetty embedded has a jetty.xml for the configuration. This configuration has a mysql jndi-connection.

When I run jetty with gradle, it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:364)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:754)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(XmlConfiguration.java:1030)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:775)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:423)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:298)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:248)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$configure.call(Unknown Source)
at com.sahlbach.gradle.plugins.jettyEclipse.JettyEclipseRun.applyJettyXml(JettyEclipseRun.groovy:533)
at com.sahlbach.gradle.plugins.jettyEclipse.JettyEclipseRun.startJetty(JettyEclipseRun.groovy:318)
```

This is the line of jetty.xml where the exception is thrown:

```
<New id="relevante" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/Relevante</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New id="relevanteDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
           <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx</Set>
           <Set name="user">xxxx</Set>
           <Set name="password">xxxx</Set>
        </New>
     </Arg>
</New>
```

The MySQL connector is a dependency of gradle and I don't know if I need to place the connector into a local address (in addition to as dependency in gradle).

```
jettyEclipse {
     additionalRuntimeJars = files( new File("$rootDir/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar") )
     warFile = file("$rootDir/build/libs/relevanteme.war")  
     jettyConfig = file("$rootDir/jetty.xml")
     contextPath = ""
     automaticReload = "true"
     scanIntervalInSeconds = 5
     webDefaultXml = file("$rootDir/webdefault.xml")
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: How is the dependency specified?

Comment: This is the dependency: compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution's to have two xml files for server configuration. One of these two files will be jetty.xml which will have all the server configuration. The other file will be jetty-env.xml with webApp configuration and connection to the database (this file has to be in webapp/WEB-INF/).

More information in [this repository](https://github.com/vjsantojaca/test-jdbc-gradle).

Answer (score 0):

What's the task to run jetty?  Do you know if there is a separate configuration for that and does it extends from compile?

Comment: I run jetty with jettyEclipse (a plugin for gradle) and a task called jettyEclipseRun. Previously, I compile and create the .war with assemble task.

Comment: No, this command, which it's the jetty plugin for Gradle, only works for to previous versions to jetty7. Since version 7,  I have to use the plugin jettyEclipse.

Comment: It looks like you have to set this option additionalRuntimeJars because I think even though you included it in your dependency, the jetty plugin does not look at that.  That option is File[] however

Comment: I have set this option to file mysql connector and it throw the same exception.